# Left Outer Join with two single columned dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, left-join

I don't see the below case mentioned in [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I'm having trouble understanding the *Pandas* documentation for doing a *left outer join*.

```
import pandas as pd

left_df = pd.DataFrame({ 
                       'user_id': ['Peter', 'John', 'Robert', 'Anna']
                       
                      })

right_df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['Paul', 'Mary', 'John',
                                     'Anna']
                       })


pd.merge(left_df, right_df, on = 'user_id', how = 'left')
```

Output is:

```
    user_id
0   Peter
1   John
2   Robert
3   Anna
```

Expected output:

```
    user_id
0   Peter
1   Robert
```

What am I missing? Is the `indicator = True` parameter a must (to create a _merge column to filter on) for *left outer joins*?

Comment: Because you asked to get all keys from left dataframe even if there is no match with right dataframe. What you want is `how='inner'`, i.e. the intesection between keys of both dataframe.

Comment: @Corralien 

Sorry, I typed my Expected output wrong.  Updated it.  "Peter" and "Robert" would be the 'left outer join'....correct?

Comment: Now you have fixed your output, `merge` is not the better option to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` with `indicator=True` and keep only rows where value is set to `left_only` but it's not the best way. You can use `isin` to get a boolean mask then invert it:

```
>>> left_df[~left_df['user_id'].isin(right_df['user_id'])]

  user_id
0   Peter
2  Robert
```

With `merge`:

```
>>> (left_df.merge(right_df, on='user_id', how='left', indicator='present')
            .loc[lambda x: x.pop('present') == 'left_only'])

  user_id
0   Peter
2  Robert
```

Comment: @Corraliean 

Thank you, I understood the indicator solution....but is it a must with merge for a left outer join?  In other words...what is my syntax saying with how = 'left'?  "Just give me back left_df"?

I like your first answer too...reminds me of the R language.

Comment: And I agree, your first solution is better.  I'm just wondering in the context of Pandas Merging 101.

Comment: Your request does not really match with the use of `merge`. Generally, we try to keep common lines (how='inner') or left rows (how='left') / right rows (how='left') whatever the other dataframe, or all lines (how='outer') of both dataframes. You can also get the cartesian product (how='cross') of all dataframes.